# How can I manually enter number of "Hours Read" in Kobo Aura HD?

Tags: kobo

I did a factory reset on my **Kobo Aura HD** ( but I did not backup *KoboReader.sqlite* file ). Now I do not have my previous reading stats.

I don't care about per book statistics but I want to manually enter "total Hours Read", how do I do that ?

UPDATE:

Following is a one row from my *KoboReader.sqlite* file *Event* table:

```
id:             11
EventType:      1021
FirstOccurence: 2015-02-17T12:20:34.000
LastOccurrence: 2015-02-17T12:21:13.000
EventCount:     2
ContentId:      file:///mnt/onboard/ebooks/Kościotrzep - Cherie Priest.epub
ExtraData:
Checksum:       ebbab9da762b1381853b5999319bed04
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way (still not simple one) is to connect your reader into linux machine and manually edit *KoboReader.sqlite* file via *sqlite3*. Now you need to know the structure of this database and try to find place where total hours read are stored. I don't have any Kobo reader so can't help you more.

Comment: Yes, You are right. There is a file `KoboReader.sqlite` and there is a table `Event` when all reading events are stored... but I can't change  values there because there is also a `checksum` table and I don't know how to calculate it.

Comment: Do you know the type of this checksum? Maybe this [What is chcecksum](http://www.geeksengine.com/article/checksum.html) will help?

Comment: I have updated my question with a row from Event table.

Comment: The Calibre plugin [Kobo Utilities](http://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=215339) makes changes to the database.  If you're fluent in Python you might look at the sources and find out about the checksum.